Project build not loading all dependencies necessary to work for another dependency
I have application (A) that depends on my library (B) packed into nuget. Lastly my library (B) uses some third party nuget library (C).
A -> B -> C

While I build my application (A) in bin directory, I can't find dll (C) that is necessary for working my library (B). I can add this dependency directly into my application (A), but I thought that it should work correctly without it.
My application and library are configured to SDK style.
Why is the dependency not loading while build process and is it correct behaviour?
